# How to retrieve records of the last 30 days from table

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SELECT  DATE_FORMAT(<dateField>, '%m/%d/%Y')
FROM <table>
WHERE <dateField>
BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 month AND CURDATE()
```

I am getting this error.

> ORA-00905: missing keyword
>   00905. 00000 -  "missing keyword"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action: Error at Line: 1 Column: 104

Also, other functions like `NOW()`, `DATE_SUB(NOW()`, `INTERVAL 30 DAY` AND `NOW()` are not working, similar error is thrown. I am unable to process the date retrieved by `SYSDATE`, as I cannot convert it using `DATE_FORMAT` function. What could I possibly do now?

Comment: how are you getting *"ORA-00905"* in your mysql db?? mysql <> oracle

Answer (score 0):

this should help hopefully.

The where clause is finding out the current server time (now()), and taking a month from it, then testing to see if the date field is greater than that value.

```
SELECT  DATE_FORMAT(<dateField>, '%m/%d/%Y')
FROM <table>
WHERE <dateField> >= date_sub(now(), interval 1 month)
```

Comment: interval 30 day would do strictly 30 days rather than one month.

Answer (score 0):

use mysql `BETWEEN` with `CURDATE` :-

```
SELECT  DATE_FORMAT(DATE_FORMAT(<dateField>, '%m/%d/%Y') ) FROM    
table WHERE <dateField> 
BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY AND CURDATE()
```

or try this :-

```
SELECT  DATE_FORMAT(DATE_FORMAT(<dateField>, '%m/%d/%Y') ) FROM    
table WHERE <dateField> BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND NOW()
```

Answer (score 0):

> ORA-00905: missing keyword 00905. 00000 - "missing keyword" *Cause:

`ORA-00905 is an Oracle error code.

```
SELECT  DATE_FORMAT(<dateField>, '%m/%d/%Y')
FROM <table>
WHERE <dateField>
BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 month AND CURDATE()
```

And this is syntactically incorrect in Oracle.

In Oracle, you could use:

- **TO_CHAR** to display the date into your desired format.
- **SYSDATE** to get the current date.
- **ADD_MONTHS** to go back a month

Try:

```
SELECT  TO_CHAR(<dateField>, 'MM/DD/YYYY')
FROM <table>
WHERE <dateField>
BETWEEN SYSDATE AND ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -1);
```